# Android : All SurfaceView gets full screen after I rotate mobile instead of maintaining aspect ration 4:3,

Tags: android, surfaceview

In my android application i am showing video (frame by frame) using `SurfacView`,i am showing 2,3,4 SurfaceView (videos) in one screen.
Video (`Surfaceview`) appear as per remote user start their web came(desktop application).
I have used urfaceHolder.Callback in SurfaceView.(Working perfect).
When I rotate screen all video (Surface)gets full screen on one another and didn't maintain aspect ratio of 4:3 resolution.
I had Override `onConfigurationChanged` method to hadel UI size of SurfaceViews.
I have set layout for all `SurfacView` in `onConfigurationChanged` method when mobile rotate.
All `surfaceView` gets write size ,i checked size in `surfaceChanged` method call back.
But after this, all surface gets full screen size instead of i have just  set.
( I dont ReCreate activity on my mobile rotation,not possible ).
Thanks in advance
Thanks & Regards